# Can't initialise a class in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, asp.net-core, file-io

So I'm working on an ASP.net project and ive created a few methods for saving, editing and reading text files from within in my project. As part of this I wanted to use the WebRootPath method from IHostingEnvironment to save the root path of the website as a variable and not have to hardcode that into my application. Ive had a look around and the general consensus for how to do this seems to be to create a constructor as below

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment;

        public Files (IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment)
        {
            HostingEnvironment = _hostingEnvironment;
        }
```

This works as far as it allows me to access the root path within the class through the HostingEnvironment property. The issue is as soon as I want to access the methods from another class and have to initialise this "Files" class, I get an error as its asking me to pass in a value of type IHostingEnvironment; see the error below
[Initialisation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6ila.png).

I don't really know how to do that or how to get around it. If anyone could help me work out what to do or find a workaround please that would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You made a constructor for your class which accepts an argument. So you can no longer initialize the class without argument.

So first of all your problem is not related to finding web root path, you may want to edit it. Second the solution is to make another constructor which accepts no arguments and call the other constructor in it with the required parameter.

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment;

        public Files ()
        {
                Files([The HostingEnviroment variable goes here]);
        }
        public Files (IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment)
        {
            HostingEnvironment = _hostingEnvironment;
        }
```

Comment: Good call on the title so ive changed that. 

Ive tried to implement the changes you mentioned and its not working, I get an error saying "Non-invocable member 'Files' cannot be used like a method". I was assuming its because im trying to call an uninitialized class so I tried making a new "Files" object, but in doing that but then ended up with an uninitialized IHostingEnvironment.

Comment: It looks Serge solved your problem. Glad to be able to help some somehow

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you really need the whole HostingEnvironment just to get string from appsettings, you can created just a special service , or catch it in startup. But if you still want to use HostingEnvironment in your EventClass you can inject it using Event constructor

```
public class Event 
{
  private read only Files _fileMethods;

  public Event (IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _fileMethods = new Files(hostingEnvironment);
   
        }
}
```

the same way you can inject the any special service that you can create instead of hostingEnvironment